# Reachability games with banned vertex repetition

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I have bumped into this problem while working on something model checking related and can't seem to find materials or efficient solutions for it. I couldn't even find a name for it.

We have a directed graph as our input, a starting vertex and two special vertices, the winning vertices for player A and B.

The vertices are partitioned between the two players, and starting from the starting vertex one player can move the game to another one along the edges if the current vertex belongs to them, just like in parity games or reachability games. We know that there is a path from the starting vertex to at least one of the winning vertices. The goal is to make the game reach your winning vertex, the only trick is that whatever path the game describe there can't be a repeated vertex. That is, if you would make a move that would force the gameplay to eventually repeat a vertex, you can't make that move.

It can be easly solved in 2^n n^2 where n is the graph size, but i couldn't find anything faster. I can't even prove np membership. Any ideas? :)

Comment: I figured out np membership, that's usually not that difficult. Using this version of reachability polynomially many times one can solve parity games, therefore it is unlikely that there is a poly solution, but likely that there is a quasy, probably pretty complicated tho.

Comment: Do the players take turns?  On a player's turn, can they move the current position an arbitrary number of times, or only once along a single edge?

Comment: Do you really mean "if you would make a move that would force the gameplay to eventually repeat a vertex, you can't make that move" or do you mean "if you repeat a vertex, you lose"?  I'm not sure whether the former condition can be checked in polynomial time.  It would be unfortunate to have a game where we can't even check whether our move is valid in polynomial time.  Or do you see an algorithm to check it in polynomial time?

Comment: When you write "Any ideas?", what are you asking?  What is your question?  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to be very explicit about what specifically your question is.  Are you looking for an efficient algorithm for some problem related to this game?  If so, what is the problem?